# How to start a standalone Screeps server on a clean install of Raspbian Jessie on a Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: node.js, linux, raspberry-pi, screeps

I'm a total noob when working with the Raspberry Pi.

Steps I've taken so far:

1. Completed a clean install of the latest stable release of Raspbian Jessie on a Raspberry Pi 2.
2. Downloaded and unzipped a folder containing the Screeps server files from https://github.com/screeps/screeps
3. Attempted to run the first command given in the "readme" file provided with the server files

   ```
   npm install screeps
   ```
4. Died.

From what I can gather, I need to install newer versions of npm and nodejs before attempting to install the Screeps server, but I have no background knowledge of how to do either of these tasks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The question asked pertains to the programming needed to start a server for Screeps, a real-time simulation that runs with javascript written by the user.

Comment: Can you expand on what "died" means? I presume you mean `npm` here. Do you get an error? Also, can you expand on the relevance of step 2? I would assume the `npm install` command would fetch this package from the internet, not install a local copy?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have npm installed? If not then you'll need to run a couple of commands first. (Disclaimer the commands I'm about to list are for Ubuntu 16.04 and may or may not work on Raspbian. A simple google search will give you the Raspbian equivalent but I'll leave that research up to you.)

'#' are comments and not meant to be typed into the command line.

```
sudo apt-get update       #will update your machine
sudo apt-get upgrade      #will upgrade your machine
sudo apt-get install npm  #will install npm on your machine
sudo npm install screeps  #will use npm to install screeps
screeps init              #should be preformed in the directory you want to run screeps in and the current user has read/write/execute privileges 
screeps start             # will start your screeps server
```

the very last command could be substituted with

`screeps start --host x.x.x.x` #the 'x' indicate the ip of the raspberry pi so that it knows where it will be receiving request

Comment: If this worked for you please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You likely ran out of memory. (npm takes a lot of memory to run)
Try increasing your swap space to have at least 2gb of usable memory.

Edit `/etc/dphys-swapfile`, change CONF_SWAPSIZE to = 1024 or 1536 and reboot.